# How to define tileset position in cesium

Tags: cesiumjs

I am trying to explore cesium 3d tileset. but I did not find a way to position tileset.

I tried transformation and bounding volumes in tileset.json but that wont work.

```
{
  "asset": {
    "version": "1.0"
  },
  "properties": {
    "Height": {
      "minimum": 20,
      "maximum": 20
    }
  },
  "geometricError": 70,
  "root": {
    "refine": "ADD",
    "transform": [
        1.0001,0,0,
        0,1,0,0,
        0,0,1,0,
        0,0,0,1
  ],
  "boundingVolume": {
    "region": [
  -1.3197004795898053,
        0.6988582109,
        -1.3196595204101946,
        0.6988897891,
        0,
        30
      ]
    },
    "geometricError": 0,
    "content": {
      "uri": "instancedOrientation.i3dm"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found how to position tileset in cesium.
Just change translation in transform matrix

```
tileset = cviewer.scene.primitives.add(new Cesium.Cesium3DTileset({
        url : url
}));

//Original location of tileset
let pos = {
    x: 1214939.1184933728,
    y: -4736505.884059093,
    z: 4081598.457967,
};

tileset._root.transform[12] = cviewer.camera.position.x - pos.x;
tileset._root.transform[13] = cviewer.camera.position.y - pos.y;
tileset._root.transform[14] = cviewer.camera.position.z - pos.z;
```

Answer (score 0):

I recently had to do this but I also needed a rotation and a scale.

Here's a [demo](https://storage.googleapis.com/jdultra.com/cesium/cesium-tileset-referencing/index.html)
And the [code](https://github.com/ebeaufay/cesium-tileset-referencing)

It seems that today, the correct way to transform a tileset in cesium is through the tileset.modelMatrix

Here's the function that calculates the transformation matrix given lon/lat/height coordinates, a rotation and a scale with the correct matrix multiplication order:

```
function computeTransformationMatrix(lon, lat, height, rotation, scale) {

    const location = Cesium.Cartesian3.fromDegrees(lon, lat, height);
    const translationMatrix = Cesium.Transforms.eastNorthUpToFixedFrame(location);

    const scaleMatrix = Cesium.Matrix4.fromScale(scale)

    const rotationMatrixX = Cesium.Matrix3.fromRotationX(rotation.x);
    const rotationMatrixY = Cesium.Matrix3.fromRotationY(rotation.y);
    const rotationMatrixZ = Cesium.Matrix3.fromRotationZ(rotation.z);

    const rotation3 = new Cesium.Matrix3();
    Cesium.Matrix3.multiply(rotationMatrixZ, rotationMatrixY, rotation3);
    Cesium.Matrix3.multiply(rotationMatrixX, rotation3, rotation3);

    const rotationMatrix = Cesium.Matrix4.fromRotation(rotation3);

    const matrix = new Cesium.Matrix4();
    Cesium.Matrix4.multiply(translationMatrix, scaleMatrix, matrix);
    Cesium.Matrix4.multiply(matrix, rotationMatrix, matrix);

    return matrix;
}
```